# Debug errors for "Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable"

Tags: htaccess, updates, permissions, upgrade

I'm system administrator, and quite befuddled as I find way to make a debug to know why error message you receive one of my users when trying to update their plugins.

- Server Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.5.32
- PHP in mode SuPHP (webserer run php how user process)
- Wordpress 4.4.2
- Directories (all on wordpress, are writeable por user with 755 pemisssion)

`.htaccess` content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When try to upgrade any plugin.

> ```
> An error occurred while updating ShareThis: Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
> ```

Weel, when I click for update I'm loogin with

```
tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log /path/wp/error_log /path/wp/wp-admin
```

Any errors show.

After some read post, try:

Add to wp-config.php

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'uploads' );
define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/'.'tmp') ;
```

Of course, create and verify owner & permissions of wp-content/tmp & wp-content/uploads

```
ls -lisa wp-content/
total 44
20188651 4 drwxr-xr-x. 10 alibera alibera 4096 Mar  4 21:38 ./
20186847 4 drwxr-xr-x.  5 alibera alibera 4096 Mar  5 10:09 ../
20242433 4 drwxr-xr-x.  3 alibera alibera 4096 Mar  4 21:31 files/
20188684 4 -rw-r--r--.  1 alibera alibera   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
20188652 4 drwxr-xr-x.  4 alibera alibera 4096 Jan 16 19:16 languages/
20188685 4 drwxr-xr-x. 10 alibera alibera 4096 Mar  4 17:50 plugins/
20189710 4 drwxr-xr-x.  7 alibera alibera 4096 Jan 16 19:16 themes/
20242436 4 drwxr-xr-x.  2 alibera alibera 4096 Mar  4 21:38 tmp/
20188683 4 drwxr-xr-x.  2 alibera alibera 4096 Feb 18 17:24 upgrade/
20189566 4 drwxr-xr-x.  9 alibera alibera 4096 Feb 18 17:24 uploads
```

Verify mod_sec log for test if mod_sec it's activate on domain, and result it's not mod_security for this domain. Any errors en log mod_security

I'm desperate, and what bothers me most is not being able to see the debug valid to analyze why

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related with a [misconfiguration of the temporary directory in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) which is used for uploads and need to be writable when the sever downloads a WordPress, plugin or theme package.

If you can not configure it at PHP level, you can define it also in wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp/');
```

Comment: Not it's problem. Problem are some plugins (diferents for every issue). If youy read my port, you read Apache+SuPHP. On this configuration there're any problem with permissions files and dirs. Aslo if you read post, see same that you write... diferent only on temp instead tmp and other minors diferences for write same instruction.

Comment: I read your question in another forum where you didn't add so much information and I skipped several lines here. Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, I don't understand what you mean with "Problem are some plugins (diferents for every issue)". What "every issue" if you asked only about one issue?. Can you explain it? Also, please, If you found a solution, post it as an answer, it will be useful for other users with the same problem, which is the main purpose of this community.

Comment: Issues for almost 5 customers (server shared) 2 cases plugins with gorgeus porblems. Other a problem  with path (customer came form server with /home2 instead /home). Other a problem with a mistake php.ini personalized on /home/user folder. I don't write a solution, becauseevery issue are a diferent question. Apreciate your time.

Comment: In that case, I vote to close the close becaise it is [too localized](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).